# How to make a NSURLSession repeat at a certain interval?

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession, nsurlsessionconfiguration

I am interesting to make `NSSession` repeat itself at a certain interval without using an `NSTimer` object, I am looking if I can set some property of the `NSURLRequest` or of the `NSURLSessionConfiguration` that I have overlooked?

Comment: In what conditions do you want to repeat ? Is there any event? or Change in some variable's value ?

Comment: so if I am on a certain view I just want to make a post to the server at an interval(let's say 5 min) and retrieve some data, I am not interested in background fetching

Comment: as you are certain about the time interval, why don't you do it with NSTimer. Are you facing any problem with that?

Answer (score 1):

if you don't want to use NSTimer, you can use long pool technic, in which you can configure the timeoutinterval.

```
(void)longPoll
{
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
NSMutableURLRequest *request    = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData timeoutInterval:30];

// --- Your code ---

[request release];
[pool drain];

[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector( longPoll ) withObject:nil];
}
```